# How to retrieve unique rows where multiple children that reference it exist for different types?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

```
SELECT * FROM Fruit
INNER JOIN Apple ON Fruit.Id = Apple.FruitId
WHERE Apple.Type = 1 AND Apple.Type = 3
```

I need to get unique rows of Fruit that have both Apples that are of type 1 AND 3. Apple.Type is considered unique, but I wouldn't think it matters though.

With these rows, this should return two rows with both Fruit #50 and #52. The most important part is the Fruit.Id, I don't need to return the Types, but just need to make sure every single Fruit returned has at least one Apple.Type = 1 and one Apple.Type = 3.

```
Apple { Id = 1, FruitId = 50, Type = 0 }
Apple { Id = 2, FruitId = 50, Type = 1 }
Apple { Id = 3, FruitId = 50, Type = 3 }
Apple { Id = 4, FruitId = 51, Type = 1 }
Apple { Id = 5, FruitId = 51, Type = 2 }
Apple { Id = 6, FruitId = 52, Type = 3 }
Apple { Id = 7, FruitId = 52, Type = 1 }
Apple { Id = 8, FruitId = 52, Type = 2 }
Fruit { Id = 50 }
Fruit { Id = 51 }
Fruit { Id = 52 }
```

I'm not quite sure how to use **DISTINCT** and/or **GROUP BY** in order to form this query.

Comment: How about some ddl and sample data? sqlfiddle.com is a great place to start.

Comment: As to your query: This doesn't work of course, because a record cannot have type 1 and 3 at the same time. It is a GROUP of records, where both types may occur or not. So using GROUP BY is one approach to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group your apples table by fruit id and pick the results that have both desired types. Use this to get your fruits.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Fruit
WHERE id IN
(
  SELECT FruitId
  FROM Apple 
  WHERE Type IN (1,3)
  GROUP BY FruitId
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Type) = 2
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This would return the fruits with ID 50 and 52.

```
SELECT *
FROM Fruit
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Apple
    WHERE Type = 1 AND Apple.FruitId = Fruit.Id
) AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM Apple
    WHERE Type = 3 AND Apple.FruitId = Fruit.Id
)
```

Comment: Thank you, this solution works perfectly, but Thorsten's is more flexible though.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way, but transposing those columns out so you have multiple types per fruitid should do it.

```
create table type_1 as select FruitId, Type as Type1 from Apple where Type = 1;
create table type_3 as select FruitId, Type as Type3 from Apple where Type = 3;
create table Fruits as select distinct FruitId from Apple;
create table Fruit_Agg as select a.FruitId, b.Type1, c.Type3 from Fruits a left join type_1 b on a.FruitId = b.FruitId left join type_3 c on a.FruitId = c.FruitId;
create table Types_1and_3 as select FruitId from Fruit_Agg where Type1 = 1 and Type3 = 3;
```